# c# initialize expandoobject from list<T>

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

I want to initialize an expandoObject from List.

```
internal class CarKeyValue {
    public CarKey CarKey { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

public enum CarKey {
    Brand = 1,
    Model = 2,
    Year = 3,
    FactoryLocation = 4,
    //more than 400 key here...
}

var car = new List<CarKeyValue>{
    new CarKeyValue {CarKey = CarKey.Brand, Value1 = "Ford"},
    new CarKeyValue {CarKey = CarKey.Model, Value1 = "Focus",Value2 = "Titanium"},
    new CarKeyValue {CarKey = CarKey.Year, Value1 = "1995"},
    new CarKeyValue {CarKey = CarKey.FactoryLocation, Value1 = "Turkey",Value2="Bursa"},
        };

dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
foreach(var item in car){
    expando.[item.CarKey].Value1 = item.Value1;
//Incorrect primary expression.
    expando.[item.CarKey].Value2 = item.Value2;
}
```

How I do that? I need to use Expando Object. I try to use `IDictionary<string,dynamic>` but that thrown another exception.

Is there any possible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is here. I use IDictionary. Not neccessary using Foo() or something else. This code block working well.

```
IDictionary<string,dynamic> expando = new ExpandoObject();
foreach(var item in car) {
     expando.Add(item.CarKey.ToString(),null);
     expando[item.CarKey.ToString()] = new { Value1 = item.Value1,Value2 = item.Value2 };
}
```

Comment: That is what I told you. Whether you use a anonymous class or not, you still can't use an enum as the key and you have to instantiate it first.

Comment: Ok, I know that to cant use enum but we focused different things, I needed a solution and I found it. May be I use wrong your way but it is not working for me. If you have a working .net fiddle example I want see it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but it makes no sense. You have to cast your expando object to `IDictionary<string, object>` or `IDictionary<string, dynamic>`.

```
IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
foreach (var item in car)
{
    expando[item.CarKey.ToString()].Value1 = item.Value1;
}
```

The above code fails because you never assign a value to `expando[item.CarKey.ToString()]`. Instead you want to set a property from a non-existing object. Regular code would have thrown a `NullReferenceException` here. (You can read the above code as `expando.SomeProperty.Value1`, where `SomeProperty` is `null`.)

So once you have set the object to an instance of something, you can use it, but then there is not much use in using the `ExpandoObject` any more:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
expando[item.CarKey.ToString()] = foo;
foo.Value1 = item.Value1;
```

Comment: Thanks to reply, I try that but again I fail. Note: I'm sorry about my question. I wrote wrong that 'expando[item.CarKey].Value1 = item.Value1;' I edited my question. True code is 'expando.[item.CarKey].Value1 = item.Value1;'

Comment: You did nothing with my answer.

Comment: Nope I try with Foo()
`expando[item.CarKey.ToString()] = foo;` is thrown exception: Additional information: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'

Comment: Works fine here.